# How to block simultaneous user login from different tabs in the same browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

My application uses spring3 mvc, I want to redirect the user to the same page if the user open two tabs & try to login simultaneously using different userId's .

Like the gmail functionality, if two users login from two different tabs the first user will get logout & see a session timeout message.

Answer (score 2):

Several tabs of the same browser use the same session, so if you just forbid access to the login page to already logged in users, this situation should never happen.

The only possibility to do that is if cookies are not supported by the browser, and the container falls back to URL rewriting to maintain sessions. In this case a user could have two simultaneous sessions in the same browser. But in this case, you could simply force the usage of cookies for your webapp.

Comment: Thanks, I have forced use of cookies.
But now I can open the login page in two different tabs and submit both with different login credentials. Say I submit tab1 with user1, pass1 then tab2 with user2, pass2.
In this situation the user1 session is getting invalidated and he gets error on clicking any links etc. I want to prevent this and show a message to the user1 saying he is logged out.

Comment: If the user opens the login page twice when not logged in, this won't quite work.  You need to actually enforce something in the form itself.

Comment: @Don Roby, exactly this what Iam looking for.

Comment: @JB Nizet thanks this works for the same user. But this will fail if some one logs from different tabs using different userIds.

Comment: No. You start by opening two tabs on the login page. In the first page, you login with user1. Then you go to the second tab, and log in with user2. The request coming from this second login is associated to the same session as the one in the first tab, and from the session, you know that this request comes from user1, so you display an error message saying "You're already logged in as user1".

Comment: @JB Nizet you are right,I have added a servlet filter to do the session check
  if (request.getSession(false) == null) {
                       //Not the first request
                  }
But some how this is not working if I try to login immediately from second tab. 
If there is some delay between the two submits then this solution works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try below attached code.

While clicking on Login Set A Key in Local Storage with some key (Example 'Y'). Place the Below Mentioned in Common File which will be available in entire application. The Below Event will be Triggered when the Value of the Local Storage is Changed. when the Value is Y. Call Logout Function. After login clear the Local Storage.

```
While Clicking login - > CLEAR_USER_SESSION - > Y - This will Logout other Session's of the Same Application in the Same Browser as per the Below Code.

After Login - Change the Value to N or Empty - CLEAR_USER_SESSION  - > 'Y' or ''

window.addEventListener('storage', function(event) {
      if (event.key == 'CLEAR_USER_SESSION') {
        var winUrl = window.location.href;
        var terminateSession =event.newValue;
        var homepage = "N";
        if(document.getElementById("empTrId")){
            homepage = "Y";
        }

        if(terminateSession && terminateSession.trim() == "Y" && !winUrl.includes("loginAction.do?method=logout") 
                && !winUrl.includes("login.jsp") && homepage == "N"){
            logout();
        }
      }
    });
```